# How to generate PreparedStatements in a multi-thread-environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, prepared-statement

I've had a working version of multi-threaded code, however I was unsatisfied with my PreparedStatement-wrapperclass being non-threadsafe. So I decided to generate the PreparedStatements in a `ThreadLocal` to make the wrapper threadsafe.

Immediately the SQLExceptions startet to hail down on me. The underlying Oracle-error is an `ORA-00060 deadlock detected` which should - according to the internet - only occur in write scenarios. My statements are all read-only. It occurs in some obscure ACL-package which I've neither heard of nor accessed consciously.

I've with some time and effort prepared and tested a hypothesis which is, generating a `Connection` object and preparing a statement from that Object from a `DataSource` object should not occur at the very same time because the access control of the database might not be "threadsafe" (althoug DataSource most certainly is). Can someone confirm or deny that finding?

If this is indeed the case, is there a best-practise how to avoid that PreparedStatements are generated at the very same time in a multithreaded application?

EDIT: As asked the text of the exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
ORA-06512: at "XXX.PKG_ACL", line 129
ORA-06512: at "XXX.PKG_ACL", line 459
ORA-06512: at "XXX.PKG_UTILS", line 1933
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone confirm or deny that finding?

I haven't heard anything along those lines, and if it does exist, it might purely be an implementation detail. Can you post your stack trace (by stripping personal info of course)?

Also, any reason why you are trying to make `PreparedStatement` thread safe rather than relying on the prepared-statement pool/cache? Or more specifically, what kind of analysis drives you to implement a `ThreadLocal` `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: I have a scenario with a fixed set of n db-accessors, all of which have their very personal PreparedStatement to access the DB. I understand, in theory the datasource should take care of the pooling. The problem seems to be, that generating n PreparedStatements at the very same time leads to a deadlock in the database. I'm not trying to make the statement threadsafe.

Answer (score 2):

A statement belongs to a connection, and a connection cannot really be used concurrently. A thread typically should "own" a connection first, before executing statements on it. So just follow the idiom

```
1 check out connection
2 prepare statement
3 execute query
4 return connection
```

You can't avoid [1] and [4], they are necessary; not too expensive anyway if pooled.

You want to cache [2], that's not necessary either, the driver probably already does the caching.

Comment: I do not access connections in a multithreaded manner. The code is (more or less) `run() {datasource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql); do_some_stuff()}`. Datasource is threadsafe, but I belive the database might not be "threadsafe" despite anything jdbc does on top of it.